# What does ?. datatype mean in SML?

Tags: syntax-error, binary-search-tree, sml

I am writing an SML binary search tree code and I am debugging the inorder, preorder, and postorder. I keep getting an error that says:

```
stdIn:11.1-11.30 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ?.tree * string
  operand:         tree * string
  in expression:
    preOrderWrite (t4,"tree.txt")
```

I know what tycon mismatch is, but I don't know why tree has a ?. in front of it. This is the tree:

```
val t4 = node(8, node(5, node(2, leaf, leaf), node(6, leaf, leaf)), node(11, leaf, node(12, leaf, leaf)));
```

And this is the code for the orders:

```
fun preOHelp(leaf) = []
        | preOHelp(node(data, left, right)) = [data] @ preOHelp(left) @ preOHelp(right);
    fun preOrderWrite(tree,fileName) = let
                                        val outfile = TextIO.openOut(fileName)
                                        val theList = toText(preOHelp(tree))
                                    in
                                        TextIO.output(outfile, theList); 
                                        TextIO.closeOut(outfile)
                                    end;

    inOrderWrite : tree * string -> unit*)
    fun inOHelp(leaf) = []
        |inOHelp(node( data, left, right)) = inOHelp(left) @ [data] @ inOHelp(right);
    fun inOrderWrite(tree,fileName) = let
                                        val outfile = TextIO.openOut(fileName)
                                        val theList = toText(inOHelp(tree))
                                    in
                                        TextIO.output(outfile, theList); 
                                        TextIO.closeOut(outfile)
                                    end;
                                    
    postOrderWrite : tree * string -> unit*)
    fun postOHelp(leaf) = []
        | postOHelp(node( data, left, right)) = postOHelp(left) @ postOHelp(right) @ [data];
    fun postOrderWrite(tree,fileName) = let
                                        val outfile = TextIO.openOut(fileName)
                                        val theList = toText(postOHelp(tree))
                                    in
                                        TextIO.output(outfile, theList); 
                                        TextIO.closeOut(outfile)
                                    end;
```

And this is the to text code:

```
fun toText [] = ""
        | toText[x,xs] = Int.toString(x)^" "^toText(xs);
```

Comment: BTW: it's simpler (and more efficient) to not first convert the tree to a list, but instead have functions that take an `outstream` to write to.

Answer (score 1):

> What does ?. datatype mean in SML?
>
> ```
> stdIn:11.1-11.30 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
>   operator domain: ?.tree * string
>   operand:         tree * string
>   in expression:
>     preOrderWrite (t4,"tree.txt")
> ```

To be honest, I'm not sure. I think the `?.` refers to an unknown module. If you find the SML/NJ error messages hard to read, consider trying out [Moscow ML](https://mosml.org/).

---

Here are a few comments:

- When you submit code as part of a question, make sure your example code does not depend on parts that must be guessed. In particular, the `'a node` datatype is missing. It should look like this,

  ```
  datatype 'a tree = leaf | node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
  ```
- The function `toText` isn't working because of a mixup between parentheses and brackets:

  ```
  fun toText [] = ""
    | toText[x,xs] = Int.toString(x)^" "^toText(xs);
  ```

  should be

  ```
  fun toText [] = ""
    | toText (x::xs) = Int.toString(x) ^ " " ^ toText(xs);
  ```
- There are some stray comments in the code: These lines are comments, but did not start with `(*`. It's obvious because they end with `*)`, but they will seem like syntax errors until you comment them out properly:

  ```
  (* inOrderWrite : tree * string -> unit*)
  (* postOrderWrite : tree * string -> unit*)
  ```

After fixing those three, the code compiles.

---

If you want to traverse a tree and do something in each node, here is an example of pre-order folding of a tree, and writing each node value pre-order to a file:

```
fun preorder_treefold f acc0 leaf = acc0
  | preorder_treefold f acc0 (node (x, left, right)) =
    let val acc1 = f (x, acc0)
        val acc2 = preorder_treefold f acc1 left
        val acc3 = preorder_treefold f acc2 right
    in acc3 end

fun preorder_write_tree_to_file (tree, filename) =
    let val outfile = TextIO.openOut filename
        fun writer (s, ()) = TextIO.output (outfile, Int.toString s ^ "\n")
        val _ = preorder_treefold writer () tree
        val _ = TextIO.closeOut outfile
    in () end
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `preOrderWrite` expects a different type `tree` than the type called `tree` that is the type of `t4`.

This usually occurs if you happen to redefine the type in the REPL *after* defining a function that works on it.
(Even if two type definitions are identical, SML considers them to be distinct types.)

Example:

```
- datatype T = T;
datatype T = T

- val t = T;
val t = T : T

- fun f T = T;
val f = fn : T -> T

- f t;
val it = T : T

- datatype T = T;
datatype T = T

- f T;
stdIn:17.1-17.4 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ?.T
  operand:         T
  in expression:
    f T
```

Note that `t`, defined earlier, has this previous type and still works with `f`:

```
- t;
val it = T : ?.T

- f t;
val it = T : ?.T
```

The most convenient solution is usually to restart the interpreter and load all definitions again.